# Сериализовать объекты класса в json формат

Tags: php, json, сериализация

Прошу подсказать по учебной задаче.

Требуется модифицировать класс Accessor таким образом, чтобы его объекты можно было сериализовать при помощи serialize() и восстановить при помощи unserialize(). По возможности организовать сериализацию таким образом, чтобы объект сохранялся в JSON-формате.

```
require_once 'include.php';
$obj = new Accessor();
print_r($obj->jsonSerialize());
```

Файл include.php:

```
class Accessor implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $array = ['key1' =>'1','key2' =>'2','key7' =>'7'];
    private $go = 123321;
    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return $this->array;
    }
}
```

Почему jsonSerialize() не отрабатывает?

Comment: что значит не отрабатывает? что вы хотите получить на выходе тут? параметр конструктора у вас какой?

Comment: вы возьмите и прочитайте описание этого интерфейса и метода, и в паре с чем он используется. В целом метод предназначен для вызова внутри `json_encode`, а не для самостоятельного. Ваш пример тут не описывает суть этого интерфейса. Вы, вероятно, думаете, что этот метод вернут json-закодированные данные, но на самом деле он должен вернуть набор данных, которые будут закодированы от объекта при вызове Json_encode этого объекта. То есть не сериализует объект, а дает данные, которые должны быть сериализованы.

Comment: передайте в объект при его вызове значения, чтобы они инициализировались в конструкторе и будет вам магия 

$obj = new Accessor(['key1' =>'1','key2' =>'2','key7' =>'7']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте внесем некоторую ясность  ваш вопрос. Сначала вы пишите про функции стандартной сериализации в пхп - [`serialize()/unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php). Они сохраняют переменную в строку в своем неком формате.
Пример:

```
class Accessor { 
    private $data = [
                'key1' => 'value1',
                'key2' => 2,
             ];

    private $val = 100;   
}


$a = new Accessor();    
print  serialize( $a );
```

на выходе получим строку следующего формата (она не совсем корректна, т.к. содержит непечатные символы, которые сюда не копируются)

```
O:8:"Accessor":2:{s:14:"O:8:"Accessor":2:{s:14:"Accessordata";a:2:{s:4:"key1";s:6:"value1";s:4:"key2";i:2;}s:13:"Accessorval";i:100;}
```

Данный метод сохранения весьма широко использовался лет так 10 назад, до начала массового использования JSON. Одно из его преимуществ относительно JSON в том, что он содержит информацию о типах. В самом  начале идет строка `O:8:"Accessor"` (O-объект, 8 - длина имени класса, далее название класса). Поэтому с помощью метода `unserialize` вы получите экземпляр этого же класса.
Недостатком относительно JSON является тот факт, что этот формат не переносим между другими языками. Это внутренний формат для пхп.

А вот JSON  напротив, является форматом обмена данных между разными системами но при этом сам по себе не содержит сведений о используемых типах данных.

Эти методы сериализации при вызовах используют "магические" методы объектов [`__sleep()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) и [`__wakeup()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup), при их наличии в классе объекта, либо если класс поддерживает интерфейс  [`Serializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.serializable.php).
Данный функционал позволяет получить данные объекта, которые следует сериализовать (чтобы не записывать объект целиком), а также выполнить действия по восстановлению состояния после того как объект десериализован.

Далее про кодирование в JSON. Для этих целей используются функции [`json_encode()/json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php). `private` поля класс не сериализуются. В случае приведенного выше класса, код

```
print  json_encode( $a );
```

вернeт "пустой объект" -  строку `{}`. Если же поля будут объявлены как `public`, то объект будет сериализован в следующую JSON-строку:

```
{"data":{"key1":"value1","key2":2},"val":100}
```

Теперь в вашем коде использован интерфейс [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.jsonserializable.php). Как и в случаях с `serialize()` и методами `__sleep()` и `Serializable::serialize` этот инетерфейс позволяет получить данные объекта, которые должны быть сохранены. Когда вы хотите сериализовать объект вы все так же вызываете `json_encode($a)`, если объект не поддерживает указанный интерфейс, то происходит сериализация всех доступных полей. Если же переданный объект его поддерживает, то будет вызван метод `jsonSerialize()` и сериализованы будут только те данные, которые он вернет.

Это позволяет во-первых сериализовать не все подряд, а только нужное, во-вторых - позволяет сериализовать любые поля, которые мы сочтем нужным, поскольку сами формируем массив значений (то есть вручную сохраняем, например, приватные поля).

Поэтому вернув в класс `private` поля и добавив данный интерфейс:

```
class Accessor implements JsonSerializable {
    private $data = [
                'key1' => 'value1',
                'key2' => 2,
              ];

    private $val = 100;

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

вызов `json_encode($a)` вернет нам только значения массива `data`:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":2}
```

Если нам требуется сохранить значения и `$data`и `$val`, то мы определяем метод соответствующим образом:

```
public function jsonSerialize(){
    return ['data' => $this->data, 'val' => $this->val];
}
```

В общем, тут надо понять, что сам метод `jsonSerialize` ничего не кодирует, а просто предоставляет данные, которые должны быть закодированы.

И возвращаясь в вашему вопросу. Невозможно сказать, как следует модифицировать класс, который указан в задании, поскольку я так понимаю это не его первоначальный вид. Во вторых инструменты `serialize()` и формат `JSON` в принципе никак не связаны в пхп. Нельзя добиться, чтобы `serialize` вдруг вернул json-строку,он возвращает свой формат. Но для этого можно использовать другие инструменты, такие как `json_encode`.

Answer (score -1):

В зависимости от того, что вы хотите сделать.
Если нужно, чтобы возвращался сериализованный массив из свойства array при вызове метода `jsonSerialize()`, то пропишите в нем:

```
return json_encode($this->array);
```

То же самое сделайте для `unserialize`, только `json_decode`.

Если же вы хотите, чтобы все работало при вызове именно функции php `serialize`, то так, увы, не получится, ввиду того, что метод встроенный и алгоритм его работы уже определен.

Есть способ переопределить этот метод через C в движке php. Но я не думаю, что в этом состоит задача.

Comment: вы заметили, что `jsonSerialize` это не метод, написанный автором просто так, а метод интерфейса `JsonSerializable`, и вряд ли он  должен сам кодировать массив в json ?